# Changing the background color on focused select box option does not work

Tags: css, focus, drop-down-menu

This is specifically with the selectBoxIt jQuery plug-in, using the jQueryUI theme.

I have this set up for the hover action:

```
/* Individual Option Hover Action */
.selectboxit-option .selectboxit-option-anchor:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

That works fine. When I hover my mouse over the options, I get a red background with white text.

However, when I do this...

```
.selectboxit-option:focus .selectboxit-option-anchor:focus  {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

...nothing changes.

I see that all the demos on selectBoxIt's main web page DO have changing background colors with keyboard focus...so what am I missing?

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle. i cant see anything wrong with what you gave

Answer (score 0):

Technically, each option doesn't use the focus event, which is why the focus pseudo selector is not working for you. For the jQueryUI theme, the "active" option adds the ui-state-focus class, so to change the "focus" CSS style, you could have a rule like this:

```
.selectboxit-option.ui-state-focus {
  background: #CCC;
}
```